# How to give Property Name in linq orderBy based on string Property name in C#

Tags: c#, system.reflection, c#-9.0, c#-7.1

I am doing sorting functionality based on columns name. have 24 columns while descending I am doing the switch condition based on direction doing the descending.

so I have specified switch condition based on descending for ascending only one default condition based on the incoming column name.i don't want the condition for ascending as well.
Here i am trying to get the property name and pass in order by default but it is not working.

anyone provide a better solution

```
public Static List<Students> Sort( string columnname , bool direction, List<Student> students){

Switch(columnname){
case "Name" when direction= false;
 students.OrderByDescending(n=> n.Name)).ToListAsync();
 break;

case "Marks" when direction= false;
 students.OrderByDescending(n=> n.Marks).ToListAsync();
 break;

etc 25 columns

default:         // trying to pass a column name dynamically but the order is not working

var getPropertyName = nameof(columnname);
students.OrderBy(n=> getPropertyName).ToListAsync();  //
```

tried with the incoming property name.

```
// Used reflection 
   var  convertProperty = typeof(Student).GetProperty(columnname);
  students.OrderByDescending(n=> convertProperty)).ToListAsync();
```

// but order is not working what ever order we have that executed

```
if try with a specific column name it is working
students.OrderBy(n=> n.Subjects)).ToListAsync();
students.OrderBy(n=> n.Marks)).ToListAsync();
}
return students

}
```

Comment: Your code won't compile - can you fix it?

Comment: @NetMage This is not a compiled code, I just provide a scenario to explain to understand, main aim is to get property name based on an incoming string and pass in order by linq method, but it is not working

Comment: Relative to `students`, `getPropertyName` is a constant - why do you expect `OrderBy(n => "some string")` to be useful? Same for `convertProperty` (also, in C#, types are your friend - what is the type of `convertProperty` and is it orderable?).

Comment: To sort by a dynamic (runtime) column name, you have a few choices: 1. Use `Expression` tree classes and build your own `OrderBy` lambda 2. Use [Dynamic LINQ](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) and use a string `OrderBy`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second last of your examples is actually quite close to something that should work.

Ignoring everything around it the following should be a working version of the mentioned example:

```
// Used reflection 
var convertProperty = typeof(Student).GetProperty(columnname);
students.OrderByDescending(n => convertProperty.GetValue(n).ToString() ?? string.Empty).ToListAsync();
```

To be fair, I haven't tried out this code, so I might have made a mistake somewhere, given this is typed freely without an IDE, but it should give a general Idea, right?

**Edit**

If you are using C# 6.0 and upwards you can use null checking like mentioned above, otherwise you can also use the following

```
students.OrderByDescending(n => (convertProperty.GetValue(n) ?? string.Empty).ToString()).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks its working one problem i found is if column value is empty , suppose grid have 5  data in a column one of the column value is empty it throws exception.

Comment: Just add null checking of some sort. I have edited my answer accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use this code:

```
students = students.OrderByDescending(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(columnname).GetValue(x, null)).ToList();
```

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I posted :)